# Error while running meteor on ubuntu server 14.04, after updating meteor: Exception while invoking method 'MeteorToys'

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, meteor, ubuntu-14.04

Recently I have moved a meteor app from Linux Mint to Ubuntu Server. The app worked like a charm. Then I updated meteor, as it was suggested and this error is stopping the app from running as it should. 
Any advises ?

This is the error:

> I20151012-14:52:37.826(-7)? Exception while invoking method 'MeteorToys' TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'ToyKit' of undefined I20151012-14:52:37.828(-7)?     at
>   [object Object].Meteor.(anonymous function).MeteorToys
>   (packages/msavin_mongol/server/methods.js:1:1)
>   I20151012-14:52:37.829(-7)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue
>   (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1) I20151012-14:52:37.828(-7)? 
>   at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1692:12)
>   I20151012-14:52:37.829(-7)?     at livedata_server.js:706:40
>   I20151012-14:52:37.829(-7)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue
>   (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1) I20151012-14:52:37.829(-7)? 
>   at tryCallTwo
>   (/home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.5.0.th99ec++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
>   I20151012-14:52:37.829(-7)?     at doResolve
>   (/home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.5.0.th99ec++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:171:13)
>   I20151012-14:52:37.833(-7)?     at new Promise
>   (/home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.5.0.th99ec++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:65:3)
>   I20151012-14:52:37.829(-7)?     at livedata_server.js:704:46
>   I20151012-14:52:37.828(-7)?     at livedata_server.js:708:19

Comment: If you run `meteor list` and then `meteor remove meteortoys` substituting the proper name for the toys, what happens? ps - are you trying to run the  toys in a production environment?  not a good idea...

Comment: After I uninstalled  the package called "msavin:mongol"  there were no more errors. so I did   "meteor remove msavin:mongol"  . But that package is really helpful when developing so I will contact the M Savin and  inform him about the errors.

Comment: Cool - it could be the upgrade or possible some tweak in your own code. Get in contact with M Savin but you might want to also set up another meteor service with all of the same modules but cut back on the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Since your app was working before, it is quite possible you were hit with an upgrade issue. Recently the default version of the compiler suddenly jumped from 3.x to 5.x. This causes all sorts of  `white-list` problems. But I assume this may not have impacted you. --- Even so, recently the Cordova plugin server was moved to a new server. You likely need to reset your entire program from scratch, which includes making sure you source all your plugins from NPM (and set the version numbers).

Read: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Read **11. You need to get your plugins from NPM now.**

I QUOTE

> The rules regarding sourcing your plugins can be rather confusing. The best thing to do is read the blog posts - below. Developers that use CLI can source from github, again see the blog post.

- [Cordova Plugins Registry becomes immutable](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/09/08/CPR-readonly.html) 2015/09/08
  The link in the blog post is broken. Use the link below
- [Plugins Release and Moving plugins to npm: April 21, 2015](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html)

NEW NEW [Cordova npm search page](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

With the help from :

> brianlmerritt

I saw that After I uninstalled the package called "msavin:mongol" there were no more errors.